# iOS Passbook not downloading from passbook scan

Tags: ios, passbook

I am creating an app that creates .pkpass files. The file gets downloaded properly on Android by scanning the link from a QR code and it also works on iPhone if I click on the link from the browser OR scan it with an external QRCode Scanner. But when I try to scan the QR from the Passbook app's internal QR Scanner then it reports that

```
No Pass Available for this code
```

I know that the pass is valid and the mime-type also is valid since it downloads on the iphone correctly when used by link or other QR Scanner, but not from passbook's scanner.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It also must be using HTTPS.

Comment: Its fairly easy to diagnose the _real_ problem if you connect your device to Xcode and look at the console.

Comment: I connected my iphone to xCode but logs from passbook are not displayed.  I have used this iphone for testing apps before

Comment: I guarantee you that the error will be logged unless `NSLog` is broken :). It will _not_ be a "crash" but will be in the console (which can be brought up from the bottom of the device's info screen in Xcode.

Comment: @SantaClaus I still didn't see any logs but you were RIGHT. Under the Developer settings in my iphone I can allow passkit to use HTTP and it downloaded the pass perfectly. So I guess if I install HTTPs on my server it will work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* distribute the pass over HTTPS using a certificate trusted by the device.

Comment: fyi, I just tested on a server that has SSL and it worked perfectly!! Thanks a lot.